# MongoBulkWriteError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$cond' in 'discount.$cond' is not valid for storage

Tags: mongodb, bulk

I fetch a feed daily and store it in a db.
I want during the updateOne phase add a value `discount`.
Discount is new price from feed divided with the latest value stored in the documents array `price`.
Server runs 4.0.3 version of mongodb.
I update around 100k product each run so I want something that is not so costly.

Br

```
bulk.find({
        productUrl: p.productUrl,
      })
      .upsert()
      .updateOne({
        $set: {
          productDescription: p.productDescription,
          productName: p.productName,
          slug: slugify(p.productName, {
            lower: true,
            strict: true,
          }),
          discount: {
            $cond: [
              { $lte: [{ $size: "$price" }, 1] },
              null,
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $lt: [
                      p.productPrice,
                      { $arrayElemAt: ["$price.value", -1] },
                    ],
                  },
                  {
                    $divide: [
                      p.productPrice,
                      { $arrayElemAt: ["$price.value", -1] },
                    ],
                  },
                  0,
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        },
        $push: {
          price: { value: p.productPrice, date: new Date() },
        },
        $setOnInsert: {
          views: 0,
          added: new Date(),
        },
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

[$cond](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#-cond--aggregation-) [$divide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/#-divide--aggregation-) and [$arrayElemAt](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#-arrayelemat--aggregation-) are aggregation pipeline operators.

Starting with MongoDB 4.2, you can [update with an aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#-cond--aggregation-).

In MongoDB 4.0 these operators are not available for updates,  so to accomplish this without upgrading, you will need to retrieve the result of the bulk find, mutate the documents on the application side, and then pass them back in a bulk update.